# Zendframework 2 postgresql update with "not"

Tags: postgresql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

Is is possible to pass to database the following sql query using tableGateway, if so, how would such a command look like ?

```
UPDATE table_data SET active = not active where table_data.id = 12;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Zend\Db\Sql\Expression`, this class tells `Zend\Db` that you know what you're doing and that the content of the string passed to this class shouldn't be transformed, but rather used as is.

```
// build the table gateway object
$adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$tableIdentifier = new TableIdentifier('table_data', 'public');
$tableGateway = new TableGateway($tableIdentifier, $adapter);

// create the filter
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->equalTo('id', '12');

// update table
$tableGateway->update(
    ['active' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('not active')], 
    $where
);
```